# Deep Learning: Feed Forward for Unbalanced Classes Using Tensor Flow

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

In theory, Deep Learning NN can predict a class with very few observations.  My problem, I have a class that happens less than 4% of the time.  Feeding the network data with distribution intact (96 one class and 4% the other class) results in the network predicting mostly the most common class.  Using under sampling result in a model that is able to predict 90% of the less common class, but still have a high False Positive.
I know that using F Score (with beta >= 2) in the training phase of the model will allow me to improve significantly the model performance. My question, how or where do I set my own performance metric in Tensor Flow?
Any suggestions are appreciated.
By the way, I did tune all the parameters (learning rate, momentum, etc..) performance increases but still not at the level I want.
My network has 20 inputs 5 hidden layers with 60 unites
My batch is 100 (tried up to 500), and I tried epoch from 100 to 1,200

The code is in Mathematica.

```
 netDrop1 = 
     NetGraph[<| "i1" -> BatchNormalizationLayer[], 
    "l1" -> CatenateLayer[], "l12" -> DropoutLayer[0.2], "l2" -> 60, 
    "l21" -> DropoutLayer[0.5], "l3" -> Tanh, "l22" -> 60, 
    "l221" -> DropoutLayer[0.5], "l33" -> Tanh , "l23" -> 60, 
    "l234" -> BatchNormalizationLayer[0.5] , "l34" -> LogisticSigmoid, 
    "l24" -> 60, "l2435" -> DropoutLayer[0.5], "l35" -> Ramp, 
    "l45" -> 60, "l435" -> DropoutLayer[0.5], "l36" -> Tanh, 
    "l55" -> 60, "l37" -> Tanh, "l4" -> 2, 
    "l5" ->  SoftmaxLayer[]|>, {NetPort["Input1"] -> 
     "i1" -> "l1" -> 
      "l12" -> 
       "l2" -> "l21" -> 
         "l3" -> "l22" -> 
           "l221" -> 
            "l33" -> 
             "l23" -> 
              "l234" -> 
               "l34" -> 
                "l24" -> 
                 "l2435" -> 
                  "l35" -> 
                   "l45" -> 
                    "l435" -> 
                    "l36" -> 
                    "l55" ->  "l37" -> "l4" -> "l5", {{NetPort[
        "MaritalStatus"], NetPort["Gender"], NetPort["Input"]} -> 
       "l1"}}, "Input" -> 11, "Input1" -> 2, 
       "MaritalStatus" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", marital, "UnitVector"}],
       "Gender" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", {"M", "F"}, "UnitVector"}],
       "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"no", "yes"}}]]
```

From reading publication about NN, I have decided to create a Dropout with = 0.2 at the input level, and at all subsequent levels to have Dropout at 0.5.
I have used both Tangent and ReLu (but found little differences in performance between them)
As you notice, a simple FeedForward Network
[image]
I do under sampling, the under sampling with great success:  the model is able to recall most of the yes, but still predict many negative samples as positive.

```
  <|{"yes", "no"} -> 972, {"no", "no"} -> 1082, {"yes", "yes"} -> 
  81, {"no", "yes"} -> 3|>
```

By the way, I have used these same data,and used RandomForest with a utility function with great results http://femvestor.blogspot.com/search?q=geico

Comment: By the way, Used Random Forest with a utility function, and C5.0 with a cost function with great success.

Comment: Before focusing on performance, I would suggest you should focus on balancing your dataset. You have a very unbalanced distribution, changing the metrics or tuning hyperparameters wouldn't help until unless you pre-process your data

Comment: I did balance the dataset.  Still, I get very good recall for the rarest class, and very good precision for the most common class.

Comment: Paste your code

Comment: what is your loss function? are you using cross entropy?

Answer (score 1):

To Improve the performance of the network, I added a Batch Normalization layer, and other variables that I had to remove when using Random Forest.  One of these variables is a categorical variable with 51 levels.  I made sure to add an embedding layer that will represent the values by a vector of size 10.
As the original dataset had 15 numerical variables and 9 categorical variables, I have decided to also perform dimension reduction using auto-encoding.